# Prompt in .zshrc

Tags: interactive, tmux, zshrc, .profile

When I start my terminal emulator, it either creates a new tmux session (named `$(whoami)`) or, if it already exists, attaches to that. However, I would like the ability to choose to create a new session if there is already one active.

The previous behaviour was part of my `.zshrc` script, so I figured I could put the extra logic in there. This is what I came up with in a separate script:

```
sessions=$(tmux list-sessions -F "#{session_created},#S")
sessionCount=$(echo "$sessions" | wc -l)

if (( $sessionCount > 0 )); then
  now=$(date +%s)

  echo -e "Attach to an existing session, or start a new one:\n"

  # List sessions in reverse chronological order
  echo "$sessions" | sort -r | while read line; do
    created=$(cut -f1 -d, <<< $line)
    session=$(cut -f2 -d, <<< $line)
    age=$(bc <<< "obase=60;$now - $created" | sed "s/^ //;s/ /:/g")
    echo -e "\t\x1b[1;31m$session\x1b[0m\tcreated $age ago"
  done

  echo
  read -p "» " choice
else
  # Default session
  choice=$(whoami)
fi

exec tmux -2 new-session -A -s $choice
```

Modulo the session attachment, this works. However, this *doesn't* work when it's put in my `.zshrc`. The `read` line gives an error:

```
read: -p: no coprocess
```

What's the problem?

(This is under OS X, if that makes a difference.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read -p "» " choice` is `bash` syntax for displaying a prompt before waiting for user input. In `zsh`, the equivalent is

```
read 'choice?» '
```

(That is, one word consisting of the variable name and the prompt joined by a `?`. The whole thing is quoted, although really only the `?` needs to be to prevent `zsh` from interpreting the word as a pattern.)

Comment: Thanks: I had just found this out by reading the `zshbuiltins` man page, but you beat me to the answer :)

Comment: Bonus `zsh` tip: `${#${(f)sessions}}` will give you the session count without having to call `wc`. :)

Comment: Having read the man page for zsh's `read`, there is another trick I can do to simplify this script. Specifically, the calls to `cut` can be removed if the while loop is changed to `while IFS="," read created session`